# How can I identify these two electrical components?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, pcb-design, identification, pcb-fabrication

Could you please help me in deciphering these two electrical components? I can provide schematic as well.

[image: 636M04 177AP]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDMj3.jpg)

[image: 631M05 240 AP]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, please provide the schematic.

Comment: Why not explain what the function of the PCB is?

Comment: If you have the schematic then why would you need to know what they are? Unless it was drawn by a complete *****, it will have the partref written in the schematic.

Comment: @Transistor this is a dc fan pcb.

Comment: @Lundin actually we are trying to trace back a pcb.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Where can i send you the schematic?

Comment: Using the snipping tool to capture well framed screenshots instead of photographing the screen will make your schematics more legible. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots-00246869-1843-655f-f220-97299b865f6b

Comment: @SyedAbdullahSohailShah Ok so it's a reverse-engineered schematic?

Comment: So maybe something along the lines of [HT2263MP](https://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/h/t/ht2263_r1.0_hotchip.pdf)? S-manuals claims that the marking starts with 63, it's a SOT23-6 and it's for flyback AC/DC so it suits the schematic somewhat.

Comment: Hey @Lundin, thank you for replying.

Comment: Do you believe both of them are working around the same principle? @Lundin